# Casting and Sum Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error message that states data loss might occur when casting from decimal(9,1) to decimal(7,4). This error occurs on the `sum(b.Column2...)` line.

```
    insert into @tempTable
    select a.Column1, sum(b.Column2 * c.Column3 * d.Column4)
    from dbo.Table1 as a
    join dbo.Table2 as b on specified columns
    join dbo.Table3 as c on specified columns
    join dbo.Table4 as d on specified columns
```

I have tried the following:

```
    insert into @tempTable
    select a.Column1, cast(sum(b.Column2 * c.Column3 * d.Column4) as decimal (7,4))
    from dbo.Table1 as a
    join dbo.Table2 as b on specified columns
    join dbo.Table3 as c on specified columns
    join dbo.Table4 as d on specified columns
```

I have also tried:

```
   declare @tempColumn2 decimal(7,4);

   select @tempColumn2 = cast(a.Column1 as decimal(7,4)) -- This gives me an unresolved error message.

    insert into @tempTable
    select a.Column1, sum(@tempColumn2 * c.Column3 * d.Column4)
    from dbo.Table1 as a
    join dbo.Table2 as b on specified columns
    join dbo.Table3 as c on specified columns
    join dbo.Table4 as d on specified columns
```

Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need (7,4) - is there a reason for that? can you just use (9,1) or better yet a float?

Comment: I'm curious, what are the types of `Column2`, `Column3`, and `Column4`?

Comment: Thats because that columns `a.Column1` is probably of type decimal(9,1) and you trying to cast it with a smaller type `7,4` if you have any registry with precision bigger than 7 that is what will cause data loss.

Comment: All of the columns are of decimal value.

Comment: @JorgeCampos isn't there a way to specifically force this to convert?

Comment: @YoungandFree you are asking it to trim of 2 digits from the over all number, not a good thing.  You could cast it as decimal(9,4)   To illustrate my point, this is what you are asking SQL to do

12345678.9   decimal(9,1)

123.4567     decimal(7,4)

Comment: @JiggsJedi Why would you suggest using a float? Floats are approximate and the datatypes the OP is using are exact.

Comment: @SeanLange you're right, it depends on the usage.

Comment: @JiggsJedi well as we can clearly see they are performing calculations. That means that float is absolutely not a good choice. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error message because you are attempting to squeeze the range `{-999999999.9 .. 999999999.9}` into `{-999.9999 .. 999.9999}`

The answer to "How do I fit decimal(9,1) into decimal(7,4)?" is: you don't.

Comment: This is being flagged as low-quality. Could you elaborate a bit more on your explanation?

Comment: @CodeMaverick The OP is asking how to fit a liter into a pint glass. The answer is either: 1) Don't do that. or 2) Change your liter so it's no longer a liter and make the question moot.  There's not much room for elaboration.

Comment: @Anon - I understand, it just came up in the queue, so I thought I'd ask you if you could add anything.